# Speeding up numpy

Tags: python, performance, numpy, time, numba

Is there a way to speed up the following code snippet? This is a function that accepts lidar points and converts it to Range View image Any suggestions would be appreciated. I tried using numba but didn't get much improvement.

```
def lidar_rv_projection(points, proj_H=32, proj_W=2048, proj_fov_up=10, proj_fov_down=-30.0):

    v_fov_up = proj_fov_up / 180.0 * np.pi  
    v_fov_down = proj_fov_down / 180.0 * np.pi  
    v_fov_total = abs(v_fov_down) + abs(v_fov_up)  

    depth = np.linalg.norm(points[:, :3], 2, axis=1)

    x_points = points[:, 0]
    y_points = points[:, 1]
    z_points = points[:, 2]

    x_img = np.arctan2(y_points, x_points) * -1
    y_img = np.arcsin(z_points / depth)

    proj_x = 0.5 * (x_img / np.pi + 1.0)
    proj_y = 1.0 + (y_img + abs(v_fov_down)) * -1 / v_fov_total

    proj_x *= proj_W  
    proj_y *= proj_H  

    proj_x = np.floor(proj_x)
    proj_x = np.minimum(proj_W - 1, proj_x)
    proj_x = np.maximum(0, proj_x).astype(np.int32)  # in [0,W-1]

    proj_y = np.floor(proj_y)
    proj_y = np.minimum(proj_H - 1, proj_y)
    proj_y = np.maximum(0, proj_y).astype(np.int32)  # in [0,H-1]

    order = np.argsort(depth)[::-1]
    depth = depth[order]
    points = points[order]
    proj_y = proj_y[order]
    proj_x = proj_x[order]
    
    proj_rv_img = np.full((4, proj_H, proj_W), -1,dtype=np.float64)
    proj_rv_img[0, proj_y, proj_x] = depth  # range
    proj_rv_img[1, proj_y, proj_x] = points[:, 2]  # height z
    proj_rv_img[2, proj_y, proj_x] = points[:, 3]  # intensity r
    proj_rv_img[3, proj_y, proj_x] = 1  # binary mask

    return proj_rv_img, proj_x, proj_y, points
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of valid input? Can you also specify how big is you data.

Comment: If you provide a reproducible working case is possible to identify exactly the performance of each piece of code, in order to see if it is all slow or only few rows of code suffers

Comment: Input "points" is of shape (4, 50000). This function is called in a for loop for the entire dataset.

Comment: Ok, `(4, 50000)` is quite small and this function should be fast. It may be a good idea to parallelize the encompassing for loop and not this function.

Comment: I see. Any suggestions on how to parallelize the for loop?

Answer (score 0):

If you're considering other numerical packages, using `torch` or `tensorflow` (especially if you have access to a GPU) may help substantially.  Fortunately, most `torch` and `tensorflow` functions are implemented in a similar way to `numpy`, so you probably wouldn't have to change too many functions.

Switching to `torch` or `tensorflow` will likely help with speeding up these operations if your dataset is considerably large, e.g. > 5000 points (and, since you're using lidar returns, I'm guessing somewhere between 3 and 6 dimensions).

Additionally, I noticed that you cast some variables to `np.int32` and `np.float32`.  If it is possible to cast this to a condensed representation, this may help as well. E.g.

1. `np.int16`: Limited to [-32768, 32767]. 16-bit signed representation.
2. `np.uint16`: Limited to [0, 65535].  16-bit unsigned representation.
3. `np.int8`: Limited to [-128, 127].  8-bit signed representation.
4. `np.uint8`: Limited to [0, 255].  8-bit unsigned representation

You can also try reducing the precision of your floating-point arithmetic, e.g. in half-precision (`np.float16`) rather than single-precision (`np.float32`).  Note that this will lead to an increase in errors, though the degree depends on the scale of the data and the operations performed.  For more information on NumPy data types, please see this link [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.types.html).

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have a huge input dataset.

If you have a **Nvidia GPU**, the magic solution is to use the package **`cupy`** to do the work on the **GPU** if you have one. You do not have to change any line of code: just add `import cupy as np` and your code should be magically much faster. On my machine (with a mid-range GPU & good CPU), with an input of 5,000,000 points, this solution is **17 times faster**!

If you have a **AMD/Intel/Nvidia GPU**, you can try the package **`clpy`** (which use OpenCL rather than CUDA).

If you do not have a (powerful) GPU, then you can use the `pnumpy` package which will make your code slightly faster (by mainly speeding up the sort which is quite slow).